# ASP.NET : Error - Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, upload

i'm working with ASP.NET web application project . in my Registration page i asked the user to upload a photo but when i try to upload this error shows up in the browser at line Line 83:

```
Line 81:                 comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@License", License);
Line 82:                 conn.Open();
Line 83:                 int row = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
Line 84:                 conn.Close();
Line 85:                 if (row > 0) { LabelError.Text = "DONE"; }
```

my DB table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DeliveryMen] (
    [Delivery_ID] INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]        NVARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
    [Username]    NVARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
    [Password]    NVARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
    [Email]       NVARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
    [Phone]       NVARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
    [City]        NVARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
    [License]     VARBINARY(MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Latitude]    NUMERIC (18)    NOT NULL,
    [Longitude]   NUMERIC (18)    NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Delivery_ID] ASC)
);
```

in case you need the insert function  :

```
 public void insert()
        {

            if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName != "")
            {
                byte[] License;
                Stream s = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(s);
                License = br.ReadBytes((Int32)s.Length);
                 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString);
                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
                comm.Connection = conn;
                comm.CommandText = "insert into DeliveryMen values(@License) SELECT '7'";
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@License", License);
                conn.Open();
                int row = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                if (row > 0) { LabelError.Text = "DONE"; }
            }
            else LabelError.Text = "Please upload the photo";
        }
```

Comment: Have you ever tried to specify your column as `insert into DeliveryMen(License) ...` since your table has more than one column? Maybe it try to insert it to first column without any column specification? What is `SELECT '7'` for by the way?

Comment: @SonerGönül i have done it here `insert into DeliveryMen values(@License) SELECT '7'` and this is the only way i know .. where i should specify `DeliveryMen(License) `?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **Soner Gönül** mentioned in the comments, change your `SQL` to list the `column name(s)` and the `parameter value(s)`

```
comm.CommandText = "insert into DeliveryMen (License) values (@License);";
```